# Is it possible to choose the Amazon Glacier Vault when backing up from Synology NAS?

Tags: synology, amazon-glacier

I am using Amazon Glacier Backup on a Synology NAS (rackstation). 
But the Synology backup software for glacier does not allow me to choose the vault to backup to.

This means I can not give my own name to the vault, but also I can not backup to a previously created vault (I also have this problem now after replacing a Synology rackstation).

Is there any way to choose to which vault you want your Synology to backup to?

Edit: I have now posted this question to the Synology forum also: http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=174&t=86557&e=0
If I can solve the problem I'll post the solutions here also.

Comment: I found amazon documentation about this here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#storage-class-intro

"You cannot associate an object with the Glacier storage class as you upload it. You transition existing Amazon S3 objects to the Glacier storage class by using lifecycle management. For more information, see Object Lifecycle Management."

Comment: If you have a windows machine around you also can try cloudberry explorer, it has a dialog box for creating Lifecycle rules.

Comment: Thanks for your research, but the information does not state how to access Glacier vaults. My concern is that the vault created by Synology Glacier Backup software, is only accessible by that Synology instance. Which makes backing up a moot point in case of hardware failure.

Comment: I think you may get a better response to your question on the synology forums http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewforum.php?f=228